# Can you use slime (brand) auto tire "tubeless" sealant for a bicycle tube?

Tags: tire, puncture

I'm used to using slime in my tubed tires, the [bicycle sealant](https://www.slime.com/au/products/bike/sealants/) kind with the "red trim":

[image: slime brand bicycle sealant 8oz bottle]

but I noticed some "prevent and repair flat tires tire sealant, all tubeless tires" [blue trim tire sealant](https://www.slime.com/au/products/auto/sealants/), offered in a larger size, so cheaper.

[image: slime brand motor vehicle sealant 1gal bottle]

It says in the [description](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2217/0259/files/Slime_Sealant_Comparison_Sheet_2019.pdf?90) that it seals "even larger" holes.  But doesn't mention bicycles.  Or tubes.  But does mention tubeless.

[image: Label comparison of slime brand bottles]

Can I use the blue trim "tire sealant" in standard bicycle tubes?

Couldn't seem to find an answer to this exact question, or on the [slime website](https://www.slime.com).

Comment: According to their website, the red trim stuff is also available in the 1gal size, and based on local pricing, red and blue appear to be the same price, so maybe you can find 1gal red or order it.

Comment: Try it and report back here.

Comment: i believe the blue trim has a larger particle size, and could potentially cause clogging in valves. With a large tubeless tire it can easily be added before the tire is fully mounted, for a tube you would need to push it through the valve.

Comment: A general comment: pro road teams are using tubeless sealant in their tubular tires, which have latex tubes inside. I believe that over time, as the sealant dries up, you don't want to let the tire get fully deflated lest the tube walls stick together. This may not be a thing for most riders, but if you leave your bike in the offseason, it might happen.

Answer (score 7):

According to Slime's blog, 
"The red label line of Slime products is designed specifically to stop flats in tires with tubes. Tubes are the key word here. Your bicycles, dirt bikes, hand dollies, wheelbarrows and jogging strollers with tubes are perfect candidates for the red label product."

I get the impression, and am doing more research into slime, but in a lot of these companies, the difference in the product line is more label and less chemical.  but according to info I read about the three lines they have, red is for tubes, blue is for everything else except highway-speed vehicles and yellow is for highway-speed vehicles.

https://www.slime.com/us/blog/which-slime-sealant-do-i-need.php

According to the Safety Data Sheets for the products, the three are identical, with the exception, MAYBE, of using different percentages of the three ingredients. Logically, I can see how a different amount of a chemical can make enough of a change to determine what type of tire we are fixing.  So, after researching, I would stick to the red for a tube, blue for all tubeless non-highway speed vehicles and the yellow for highway speed.  Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Loren Stevenson's answer was spot on at the time the question was originally posted, but this year Slime released both their "**Red**" line in the bulk gallon size, plus a new "**Black**" formula designed specifically to function across both ranges previously covered by their "**Red**" and "**Blue**" formulas, and it too comes in cheaper bulk gallon option. Given your question was really, "can I use any of the Slime tire sealants available in bulk gallon size in my bicycle tubes?" the answer is now clear:

Yes, either keep using the "**Red**" line as you have but in the newly-released gallon size, or move to the new "**Black**" line which covers both tubes and tubeless applications and is also available in the gallon size:

[image: Slime 2021 Product Comparison Chart]

Note: The "**Black**" line is not TPMS sensor-safe so cannot be used in any vehicle equipped with tire pressure monitoring systems, such as all current highway vehicles, hence the "off-highway" designation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work in tubeless tires, it's just not marketed for that.

It's good stuff. I've used it for years in wheelbarrows, riding mowers and boat, travel and utility trailers. It always stopped the slow leaks.